Can I check if a table exists during a left join on SAS?
I have to make a dashboard using a table generated by another team. the tables are named as table_YYYYMM -- However, the data is not always on sync, so i have to use the most recent available.
so i'd like to try to code something like:
proc sql;
create table want as
select
t1.*,
t2.column1,
t2.column2
from have t1
left join **[table_202405] OR [table_202404] OR [table_202403] (whatever is most recent)** t2  on (t1.key = t2.key);
run;

is there a way to do that?
i thougth of checking if the table exists before running the code, or perhaps some kind of max(yyyymm). but i have no idea how to code this.

No.  But you can check BEFORE you try to run that SQL statement. Then you can use the SAS macro language to conditionally generate the SAS code you need.
In this case the simplest thing is to use a macro variable to put the name of the dataset you want to use into the SQL statement.  So if you set the macro variable OTHER_DATASET to the name of the dataset you want to use then you can just run this code:
proc sql;
 create table want as 
   select t1.*, t2.column1, t2.column2 
 from have t1 left join &other_dataset t2
   on (t1.key = t2.key)
; 
quit;

Now you just need a way to assign the right value to that macro variable before running that step.
Sounds like perhaps you just need to find the name of the existing dataset that has the largest numeric suffix.  Is that right?  If so something like this should work:
Query the list of member names from the library where the datasets live and select the one you want and put its name into the macro variabe.
Perhaps something like this:
proc sql noprint;
  select catx('.',libname,max(memname)) into :other_dataset 
  from dictionary.members 
  where libname = 'MYLIB'
    and memname like 'TABLE^_%' escape '^'
  ;
quit;

If you also have datasets with names like TABLE_XYZ then you might need to impose more restrictions in that query.  For example you might check that the everything after TABLE_ is a digit string that represents an actual number.
    and not missing(input(substr(memname,7),?32.))


Thank you very much for your answer! I tested it and it worked fine on most cases. I just had one issue, as one of the tables I'm working on has a "OLD" version attached to it. when seeking between [table_202405] and [table_202405OLD], it recorded the "OLD" variant in the other_dataset variable. I'll try and look further into it

You could only look for member names that are that exact length.  That would eliminate the suffixed names.

You can use a regular expression to test for the presence of 6 digits in the name.
You should also check that a table has been found.
proc sql noprint;
  select catx('.', LIBNAME, max(MEMNAME)) into :latest_data 
  from DICTIONARY.MEMBERS 
  where LIBNAME = 'MYLIB'
    and prxmatch('/MYTABLE_\d{6}/', MEMNAME)=1
  ;
  %if %symexist(latest_data) %then %do;
  create table WANT as 
  select * 
  from HAVE          T1 
         left join 
       &latest_data. T2
         on (T1.KEY = T2.KEY)
  ; 
  %end;
quit;

